# Symfony 2 custom themes folder

Tags: symfony

I'm designing a multi-tenant application with Symfony2, There will be common templates and each tenant could have custom templates. I would like create a theme folder like this(like wordpress with css,img,etc...) :

- Themes/commons/base.twig.html
- Themes/commons/css/styles.css
- Themes/commons/js/script.js
- Themes/tenantID/base.twig.html
- Themes/tenantID/css/styles.css
- Themes/tenantID/js/script.js

Perhaps I'm taking a wrong way...?
Any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your design. I may name "commons" as "default" but thats up to you. Approach with tenantid looks good to me. Whats your question?

Comment: Thanks. 
I would like put css,img,js and templates in the same tenantID or Common folder. 

But, with symfony2, templates and css,img,js are in separate folder. 
app/Resources/views/ or path/to/bundle/Resources/views/ for templates and web/bundles/framework/ for css, img, js.

Comment: @user1123272, Have you found the answer for this? I'm looking to implement this also :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/17 - no dynamic inheritance

LiipThemeBundle might be a solution: http://symfony2bundles.org/liip/LiipThemeBundle

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve all this by following symfony standard . because if you follow structure you will make full stack full site in frame work and you can also learn how to use frame work.

like in

bundle folder:
userbulndle/css

userbulndle/js

adminbundle/css etc

and use theme forming

```
{% block gender_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if expanded %}

            {% for child in form %}

                <div class="radio_ele">
                    {{form_widget(child) }}
                        {{form_label(child) }}

                    </div>
            {% endfor %}

        {% else %}
            {{  block('choice_widget') }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}

{# ----------------------------------------------------------- #}

{% block field_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if errors|length > 0 %}
         <div class="error_list">
            {% for error in errors %}
               {{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators') }}
            {% endfor %}
       </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_errors %
```